# How to make glass refraction looks smoother?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I have this model for a glass bottle and when I preview or even render the scene out, the refraction has weird straight edges and doesn't look smooth enough. I already have applied subdivision and the bottle has quite dense geometry. Any help from the community will be really appreciated.[image: Glass Sharp Reflection/Refraction]

[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you give it a Subdivision Surface modifier?